# SQLite Android - MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, sqlite, class, methods

My application is a soundboard app, but there is a lot of sounds in categories. Each category is running in a different activity. So, the first activity call the others when the user select the category.

The app have more than 200 sounds and I started to make a SQLite DB so the user can select the favorite sounds and show them in a separate activity.

It is already working but the code is in the activity, when I put the sqlite code in a method inside another class (if I want to change something it will make my work easier because there is 20 categories) it gave me the 'cannot be resolved to a variable' for `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`.

Here's the method:

```
public void cria(String titulo,int id){
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

    try {
        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, CODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (titulo VARCHAR, id INT);");

        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('" +
                titulo +
                "'," +
                id +
                ");");

    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        //nothin to do
    }
}
```

I have tried to use (String titulo,int id, Context cont) and `cont.CODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` but then it gives error like `openOrCreateDatabase is undefined for the type banco (banco is the class name)`.

How can I use the `openOrCreateDatabase` in another class that is not an activity ? If you guys can show me a snippet.

=========EDIT===========

As zrgiu solved the problem, here goes my code in the banco class:

public class banco{

```
private final static String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "myFriendsDb";
private final static String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "friends";



public static void cria(String titulo,int id, Context cont){
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

    try {
        sampleDB =  cont.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (titulo VARCHAR, id INT);");

        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('" +
                titulo +
                "'," +
                id +
                ");");

    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(cont.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        sampleDB.close();
    }
}
```

}

And in the activity I use:

banco.cria(somestring,someint, this);

Again, thank you zrgiu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a context to create/open databases localized to your apps. The easiest way for you is just to pass a context instance to your function or class, making sure you don't leak it.

The other solution would be to store your sqlite database on the external storage, which doesn't require a Context but also exposes your database to all other apps and the user.

Comment: Thank you zrgiu. How can I pass the context correctly ? I've tried to get context in the method cria ( (String titulo,int id, Context cont) ) and it gave me another error :(

Comment: that is a good start. now you just have to make sure that everywhere you call cria(), you need to pass your context as a parameter (in an Activity class, that would be "this").

Comment: You didn't understand me, this don't work either. As I wrote, "I've tried to use (String titulo,int id, Context cont) and cont.CODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE but then "openOrCreateDatabase is undefined for the type banco" (banco is the class name)."

Comment: Ah, sorry. You need to call cont.openOrCreateDatabase instead of this.openOrCreateDatabase in your method.

Comment: Thank you so much, working now. Ill edit the first post with the right code.