# MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE giving error

Tags: android, sqlite

i am creating a project using fragment.  when i want to create database it give me error on MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE.while in other project(in which i am not using fragment) it is working  i am new to android please give a solution.

```
public class AddEmploy extends Fragment {
public AddEmploy(){

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_employ, container, false);
    final EditText name= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etemname);
    final EditText position= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etposition);
    final EditText contact= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etcontact);
    final EditText address= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etaddress);

    Button save= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("my_database", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);

            db.execSQL("create table if not exists employ( name varchar(30),position varchar(30)," +
                    "contact varchar(20),address varchar(30)," +
                    " date varchar(255)) ;");

            Date d=new Date();

            //database insert
            db.execSQL("insert into employ values('" + name.getText().toString() + "', '" + position.getText().toString() + "'," +
                    "'" + contact.getText().toString() + "','" + address.getText().toString() + "'," +
                    "'" + d + "');");


        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865945/sqlite-android-mode-world-writeable-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable

Comment: did no understand. i am new to android.

Comment: Are you sure you want/meed the database MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE?

Comment: i dont know why to use MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE. i want to create database. in other app i am using and its working but in this app its not working.

Comment: its working now. thanks. - Usman Rana

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Android - MODE\_WORLD\_WRITEABLE cannot be resolved to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865945/sqlite-android-mode-world-writeable-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)